# Phoenix 1.4 Upgrade - (FunctionClauseError) no function clause matching in Phoenix.Socket.__terminate__/2

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, phoenix-channels

I recently upgraded my Phoenix app from 1.3 to 1.4.

Everything is great except that when I navigate away from a page I’m getting the following error:

```
[error] GenServer #PID<0.509.0> terminating
** (FunctionClauseError) no function clause matching in Phoenix.Socket.__terminate__/2
    (phoenix) lib/phoenix/socket.ex:544: Phoenix.Socket.__terminate__({:shutdown, :closed}, %Phoenix.Socket{assigns: %{}, channel: MhrWeb.SearchChannel, channel_pid: #PID<0.509.0>, endpoint: MhrWeb.Endpoint, handler: MhrWeb.UserSocket, id: nil, join_ref: "2", joined: true, private: %{log_handle_in: :debug, log_join: :info}, pubsub_server: Mhr.PubSub, ref: nil, serializer: Phoenix.Socket.V2.JSONSerializer, topic: "search:query", transport: :websocket, transport_pid: #PID<0.497.0>})
    (stdlib) gen_server.erl:673: :gen_server.try_terminate/3
    (stdlib) gen_server.erl:858: :gen_server.terminate/10
    (stdlib) proc_lib.erl:249: :proc_lib.init_p_do_apply/3
Last message: {:"$gen_cast", :close}
State: %Phoenix.Socket{assigns: %{}, channel: MhrWeb.SearchChannel, channel_pid: #PID<0.509.0>, endpoint: MhrWeb.Endpoint, handler: MhrWeb.UserSocket, id: nil, join_ref: "2", joined: true, private: %{log_handle_in: :debug, log_join: :info}, pubsub_server: Mhr.PubSub, ref: nil, serializer: Phoenix.Socket.V2.JSONSerializer, topic: "search:query", transport: :websocket, transport_pid: #PID<0.497.0>}
```

I’ve tried implementing terminate in user_socket.ex and in search_channel.ex which handles the specific topics, but it hasn’t changed anything.

Any insight is very much appreciated!

Comment: What is Elixir version? What is OTP version?

Comment: Also, I’d start with `mix deps.clean` or maybe even `rm -rf _build deps`.

Comment: Thanks for the responses... Erlang/OTP 21 [erts-10.2.3] [source] [64-bit] [smp:4:4] [ds:4:4:10] [async-threads:1] [hipe] [dtrace]

Elixir 1.8.0 (compiled with Erlang/OTP 21)

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin No luck with your suggestions... still getting that same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out (it was dumb)... in each of my channel modules I needed to remove `use Phoenix.Socket` :/

Answer (score 2):

Looks like there is mismatch in the `\__terminate__` function signature and what is being passed to it.

From [the file](https://github.com/phoenixframework/phoenix/blob/v1.4.0/lib/phoenix/socket.ex#L544]), it expects the `:inverse_channels` field in the call which is missing in your call.

So if you try adding an channels_inverse(second line below) field in your call(in iex), with a sample PID in the pid0 variable

```
Phoenix.Socket.__terminate__({:shutdown, :closed}, {
  %{channels_inverse: %{}}, # this is dummy data added!!

  %Phoenix.Socket{assigns: %{}, channel: MhrWeb.SearchChannel, 
    channel_pid: pid0, endpoint: MhrWeb.Endpoint, handler: MhrWeb.UserSocket, 
    id: nil, join_ref: "2", joined: true, private: %{log_handle_in: :debug, log_join: :info}, 
    pubsub_server: Mhr.PubSub, ref: nil, serializer: Phoenix.Socket.V2.JSONSerializer, 
    topic: "search:query", transport: :websocket, transport_pid: pid0}
})
```

the function clause error goes away.

So, you will have to track where this function call without `%{channels_inverse: %{}}` is coming from. Maybe your socket-related javascript files are not updated to phoenix 1.4?

Comment: Thanks for the response... definitely gave me more to investigate.